# SQLAlchemy: How to make a hybrid_property a declared_attr?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, declarative

I would like to be able to call `Duration.create_duration_field()` with different parameters and have more than one `hybrid_property` created on my class. The only difference would be that different timestamps will be subtracted for each of them.

Of course using `declarative_attr` is not a requirement, but I need the properties to be `hybrid_property`s.

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Duration(Base):
    __tablename__ = "duration"

    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    notes = Column(String)
    timestamp_initiated = Column(DateTime,
                                default=datetime.datetime.now(),
                                nullable=False)
    timestamp_done = Column(DateTime)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @declared_attr
    def duration(cls):
        return cls.create_duration_field("initiated", "done")

    @classmethod
    def create_duration_field(cls, start, end):
        @hybrid_property
        def duration(obj):
            getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % end) - getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % start)
        @duration.expression
        def duration(cls):
            return getattr(cls, "timestamp_%s" % end) - getattr(cls, "timestamp_%s" % start)
        return duration



engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

duration = Duration(name="Test", timestamp_done=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=25))
session.add(duration)
session.commit()

assert isinstance(duration.duration, datetime.timedelta)
```

Currently `duration.duration` is a reference to `hybrid_property`

```
<sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property object at 0x1d02190>
```

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/821dbc9f57c55ca2 (when using @declared_attr on a mapped class, it only has effect on __table_args__, __tablename__ and __mapper_args__)

Comment: Thanks. I have separated `duration` and `create_duration_field` into a mixin, but the result is the same. (SQLAlchemy==0.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still at 0.6 so I can't try your fancy properties. :)

But instead of

```
class Duration(Base):
    # [...] 
    @declared_attr
    def duration(cls):
        return cls.create_duration_field("initiated", "done")
```

you could try something like:

```
class Duration(Base):

    duration = declared_attr(create_duration_field("initiated", "done"))
```

and move your *create_duration_field* classmethod off that class. That way you can also reuse it on different classes. Perhaps **declared_attr** should also be moved inside *create_duration_field*, you'll have to experiment there.

An example would be this little thing I use all the time:

```
def constructor(**kw):                                                          
    """Creates a class constructor class method"""
    def load(cls):
        query = cls.query
        return query.filter_by(**kw).one()
    return classmethod(load)
```

You would use it like this:

```
class SomeModel(Base):

    SomeInstance = constructor(primary_key=17)

instance = SomeModel.SomeInstance()
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. In your first example, there is no difference between using the decorator syntax or wrapping the method. It wouldn't work the same way. In your second example, no, I don't get the idea. It is not even relevant to my question.

Comment: The difference is in your code you wrap the "duration" method, and in my example the returned value of create_duration_field is wrapped. There IS a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the script and it's ok (0.9.6). You just need to change the code from:

```
@hybrid_property
def duration(obj):
    getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % end) - getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % start)
```

to:

```
@hybrid_property
def duration(obj):
    return getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % end) - getattr(obj, "timestamp_%s" % start)
```

Result:

```
duration.duration = 0:00:25.017861 datetime.timedelta(0, 25, 17861) <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```